# foreman smart-proxy error to register puppet

Tags: ruby, puppet, puppetlabs-apache, theforeman

I have installed `foreman` , `foreman-proxy` and `puppet` on same ubuntu 12.x box and try to add `smart-proxy` entry but i am getting following error any idea? I have drop DB and restarted but still same issue.

```
Started POST "/smart_proxies" for 10.10.50.15 at 2014-03-06 15:44:53 -0500
Processing by SmartProxiesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NwndUWNHb78ay/6KKVxDMPSb4TLwaPnNr7vMz06JwnU=", "smart_proxy"=>{"name"=>"a", "url"=>"https://spatel-optiplex-755.example.local:8443"}}
Failed to save: 
  Rendered smart_proxies/_form.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered smart_proxies/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.5ms)
  Rendered home/_user_dropdown.html.erb (1.1ms)
Read fragment views/tabs_and_title_records-1 0.1ms
  Rendered home/_topbar.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 96.3ms (Views: 6.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Comment: Yes, I had two versions of the `json` gem installed, double check,
as one of them seems to be installed incorrectly (e.g. `32bit` version
on a `64bit` ruby or the other way around). also make sure you have `:puppet: true` in `setting.yml`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, did some investigation and came across this conversation:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foreman-users/BcP3XdN-Nbo

It seems as though in my case the default foreman-proxy installation enabled the 'Facts' feature only. For some reason it was insufficient to be saved on the foreman smart proxy list. After adding more features foreman was able to save the proxy with the list of provided features (excluding 'Facts').

Hope that helps.

Comment: What 'more features' did you add? Also, were you able to save the proxy? What do you mean by "excluding 'Facts'"?

Comment: @PatrickM by features I meant the list of functionality the proxy is exposing. I added the puppet and puppetca features by modifying /etc/foreman-proxy/settings.d/{puppet.yml,puppetca.yml} and setting :enabled: true. Yes after restarting the proxy i was able to save it on foreman application. When you save the proxy you get the list of features it supports, in my case it was puppet and puppetca, while technicaly my proxy supported puppet, puppetca and 'Facts' (whatever it is and was excluded anyway). You can check what features your proxy supports by navigating to http://proxyurl/features.